# Dirichlet Class Number Formula Proof

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I'm studying Davenport's proof of Dirichlet Class Number Theorem and I'm having troubles with this statement:

> Consider the sum
>
> $$\sum_{m_1 m_2<N; (m_1,m_2,d)=1} \left(\frac{d}{m_1}\right)=
> \sum_{m_1 <\sqrt{N}} \left(\frac{d}{m_1}\right)
> \sum_{m_2 <N/m_1} 1 + ...
> $$
>
> **then** $\sum_{m_2 <N/m_1} 1 = \frac{N}{m_1}\frac{\phi(|d|}{|d|}+O(\phi(|d|)$

I've tried to solve it by using the orthogonal relations of Dirichlet characters but I didn't succeed. Any ideas?